# Is this php script safe? fwrite and get

Tags: php, .htaccess, get, xss, fwrite

The purpose of this script is to mail logs to to he webmaster whenever there is a 404/500 etc server error.

The script makes use of fwrite to count logs and then save 10 logs and mail them if it reaches 10 logs.
It uses some of value's and display's them via echo, how can I be sure it does not have XSS or an other hackable issue.
I know the script might not be as advanced, efficient or cleanly written, but it does me the trick.
I'm just concerned about it's safety.

**.htaccess file**

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/error.php?err=400
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/error.php?err=401
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/error.php?err=403
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/error.php?err=404
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/error.php?err=500
ErrorDocument 410 /errors/error.php?err=410
```

**php file /errors/error.php**

```
<?php

$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "r"); 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 
fclose($fp); 


$errorNum = (int)$_GET['err'];
$err_str = array(404=>'Type of error: Not Found (404)', 400=>'Type of error: Bad Request (400)', 401=>'Type of error: Unauthorized (401)', 403=>'Type of error: Forbidden (403)', 410=>'Type of error: Gone (410)', 500=>'Type of error: Internal Server Error (500)');

$ip = getenv ("REMOTE_ADDR"); 
$requri = getenv ("REQUEST_URI"); 
$servname = getenv ("SERVER_NAME"); 
$combine = $ip . " tried to load " . $servname . $requri; 

$httpref = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER");

if (empty($httpref)) { 
 $httpref = "Unknown Location";
}

$httpagent = getenv ("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

$today = date("F j, Y, H:i:s"); 

$note = "This information has been sent to the webmaster." ;

$message = "On $today \n <br> $combine <br> \n User Agent = $httpagent \n <br>User got there from: $httpref <br><br> $err_str[$errorNum] <br><br> $note\n ";
$message2 = "#$count \n $today \n $combine \n User Agent = $httpagent \n User got there     from: $httpref \n $err_str[$errorNum] \n\n ";

$fh = fopen("errorlogje.txt", "a") or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $message2;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

if ($count == 10) {
$count = 0;
$fh = fopen("errorlogje.txt", "r");
$bericht = fread($fh, 4096);
$to = "mail@mail.nl"; // webmaster email
$subject = "errorpage guardian has a message"; // email bericht
$from = "From: mailguardian@mail.nl\r\n";  // email afzender (makelijk voor het sorteren)
mail($to, $subject, $bericht, $from);

$fh = fopen("errorlogje.txt", "w");
fclose($fh);
}
else {
$count = $count + 1;
}

$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $count); 
fclose($fp); 

echo " $message ";

?>
```

Comment: If you think XSS, think [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: file writing is safe, since you don't use any user provided values to open the file. User agent, http referer or request uri might contain html/javascript code, follow hakre's advice for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly safe, yes.
The only `$_GET` value that you're using is casted to integer, so that eliminates any possible issues with it.

Comment: Thanks, so if I add those htmlspecialchars mentioned earlier to the echo's output its totally safe? Or that not even an issue?

Comment: Only one? How about user agent?